# Conditional formatting using Unique

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

Im trying to use conditional formatting to highlight a cell with the x'th lowest number.

```
=A$1=small(unique($A$1:$E$1),3)
```

[image: example]

Even with `unique()` I cant seem to make it ignore duplicates.
The 3rd smallest seems to be 2, not 3.
4th smallest will highlight the cell with 3 (C1).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something?

Yes, research.

```
=A1=small(unique(transpose($A$1:$E$1)),3)
```

Comment: ohh.
So, my unique was comparing the entire row to other rows, but only 1 row exist so it just return the unchanged row.